# Google App Engine: Uploading and serving a blob using webapp2

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm trying to upload and serve an image as a blob by following this tutorial:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/

Here's my main.py file:

```
import webapp2

from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

# A custom datastore model for associating users with uploaded files.
class UserPhoto(ndb.Model):
  user = ndb.StringProperty()
  # blob_key = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
  blob_key = ndb.BlobKeyProperty()


class PhotoUploadFormHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload_photo')
        # The method must be "POST" and enctype must be set to "multipart/form-data".
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        self.response.out.write('<form action="%s" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">' % upload_url)
        self.response.out.write('''Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br> <input type="submit"
            name="submit" value="Submit"> </form></body></html>''')

class PhotoUploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        try:
            upload = self.get_uploads()[0]
            user_photo = UserPhoto(user=users.get_current_user().user_id(),
                                   blob_key=upload.key())
            user_photo.put()

            self.redirect('/view_photo/%s' % upload.key())

        except:
            self.redirect('/upload_failure.html')

class ViewPhotoHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, photo_key):
        if not blobstore.get(photo_key):
            self.error(404)
        else:
            self.send_blob(photo_key)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', PhotoUploadFormHandler),
                               ('/upload_photo', PhotoUploadHandler),
                               ('/view_photo/([^/]+)?', ViewPhotoHandler),
                              ], debug=True)
```

When I try to run this application, I do get the 'upload file' option. When I chose a file to upload and submit the form, the application gets redirected to '/upload_failure.html' and I get a `404 Resource not found` error. Here's what my datastore looks like:

[image]

What seems to be wrong with the code? The image file is clearly being stored inside the datastore. However, why is the application not being able to serve the image?

Comment: If you log the exception that's being thrown instead of catching and ignoring it you might make progress.

Comment: Looks like your PhotoUploadHandler will work only when user is logged in. Most likely users.get_current_user().user_id() is resulting in an exception as users.get_current_user() is None. This you can verify by looking at UserPhoto entity , most likely you wont find any.